# Refer to base class with self when called from subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm having trouble understanding/using inheritance with `self`. The following is an MRE of the situation:

```
class Foo:
    def baz(self, num):
        if num <= 0:
            return

        print(f"Base: {num}")
        self.baz(num - 1)


class Bar(Foo):
    def baz(self, num):
        if num <= 0:
            return

        print(f"Sub: {num}")
        super().baz(num - 1)


Bar().baz(3)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Sub: 3
Base: 2
Sub: 1
```

My question is: why does `self.baz(num - 1)` in `Foo` call `Bar.baz`? I can see in my debugger that `self` refers to an instance of the `Bar` class, but I don't understand why it works this way. And whatever the answer, how do I go about referring to the current method (in `Foo`), while using the current `self` object? In other words, whether `self` currently refers to a `Foo` object or a `Bar` object, I'd like to call `Foo.baz`.

My intended output is:

```
Sub: 3
Base: 2
Base: 1
```

Comment: `Bar()` creates a `Bar` object, so `self` is `Bar` all the time. You can use `__` to avoid overriding, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Comment: And whatever the answer, how do I go about referring to the current method (in Foo), while using the current self object? - You can call `Foo.baz(self, num - 1)`.

Comment: @tevemadar I am intentionally trying to override in this case.

Comment: The self is alays the **same** instance, which started, and remains, as a Bar.   You agree there?  The self.baz lookup will therefore *always* return the baz tied to  Bar.   super gets the Foo ‘s